# ¿Cómo adquirió la palabra "bonito" su significado?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, adjetivos, historia

La palabra *bonito* es de esas palabras que usamos cotidianamente, sin pararnos a reparar en ella. Pero cuando lo hacemos, podemos darnos cuenta de que está formada como un diminutivo (acabada en *-ito*). El caso es que fui a consultarlo en el DRAE, y efectivamente veo lo siguiente:

> [**bonito, ta**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5rTR6tT%7C5rVKGkX)
>
> Del dim. de *bueno*.

Hoy en día, aplicamos el adjetivo *bueno* a las cosas según su calidad, fiabilidad, utilidad, etc. Cuando algo es bueno es que cumple con lo que se espera que haga. Sin embargo, aplicamos el adjetivo *bonito* por motivos estéticos: cuando algo tiene cierta proporción y belleza. Es decir, se pasó de un sentido de utilidad a un sentido de belleza.

¿Es posible conocer cómo, a pesar de una palabra provenir de la otra, llegó a adquirir *bonito* su significado actual? ¿Se puede determinar históricamente esta deriva?

Comment: Yo creo que es por el pez, que es muy agradable a la vista :P Pues veo que el [mapa de diccionarios académicos](http://web.frl.es/ntllet/SrvltGUILoginNtlletPub) menciona en 1780 _adj. d. de BUENO. Aliquantulùm bonus._ Además, en el Ngram empieza a aparecer hacia 1750, ergo parece algo relativamente nuevo.

Comment: @fedorqui en 1780 ya existían las acepciones _lo mismo que "bien parecido"_ y _el que presume de lindo_ para _bonito_.

Comment: En Chile (supongo que también en otras partes) de una mujer bonita decimos que "está _buena_". O sea que la deriva también puede ser a la inversa.

Comment: @Rodrigo, en Bolivia -y creo en todo Sudamerica- "esta buena" lleva una connotación de atractivo sexual. Muchas veces una mujer puede ser bonita sin precisamente "estar buena".

Por otro lado, si no me equivoco el superlativo de bueno es bonísimo (y no buenísimo). Si esto es así estaría de alguna manera relacionado con lo que CarlosAlejo menciona con respecto a la terminación -ito como diminutivo en esta palabra.

Answer (score 5):

Parece ser una transición bastante común. Copio del *Diccionario Etimológico* de Corominas (derivados de `bueno`):

> *Bonito* [1517], el significado ’lindo’ presenta un proceso semántico paralelo al del lat[ín] *bellus* ’lindo’, originariamente diminutivo de *bonus*

Etymonline [confirma](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=bene-) lo de *bellus*.

De hecho, el mismo adjetivo `lindo`...

> [...] significó primitivamente ’legítimo’, de donde más tarde ’auténtico’, ’puro’, ’bueno’, y la ac[epción] moderna [...]

<sup>Corominas y Pascual, *Diccionario Crítico Etimológico Castellano e Hispano*.</sup>

Comment: Uf, a ver si me he enterado. En latín existía _bellus_ con el significado de _bonito_. Por otro lado, tenemos _lindo_ que proviene de la misma palabra que _limpio_, _limpidus_, y que siguió un curso parecido al de _bonito_ desde _bueno_ y éste desde _bonus_. Es decir, sabemos que hubo una transición, pero no me queda claro cuándo empezó a usarse _bonito_ con el sentido de _bello_, o cuál fue dicho proceso de transición.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo A ver, al preguntar “cómo llegó _bonito_ a adquirir su significado actual”, ¿qué es exactamente lo que querés saber? ¿Cuál fue la asociación mental que hicieron los hablantes, que la palabra, de significar “buenito”, pasó a significar “lindo”? Bueno, sólo puedo conjeturarlo, pero muestro en mi respuesta que no es una transición poco común, que ya se ha dado en el latín `bonus` → `bonellus` > `bellus`, y, aunque no es un paralelo exacto, en `lindo` (que Corominas hace provenir del latín `legitimus`, además de descartar el origen `limpidus` por imposible (cont.)

Comment: (sigue) desde el punto de vista fonético). ¿Querés saber _cuándo_ se comenzó a usar `bonito` para `lindo`? Corominas lo registra en 1517. Todo lo anterior está en mi respuesta. Si no es eso lo que querés saber, por favor sé más específico.

Comment: lo siento, la verdad es que a veces me explico fatal. Te agradezco tu respuesta, de veras. Es simplemente que me gustaría saber si podríamos localizar algún paso intermedio del proceso. Sabemos que venimos de _bonus_ y llegamos a _bonito_, y que en 1517 ya tenía la acepción actual. ¿Hay registrado algún paso intermedio entre ambos? ¿Existía _bonitus_ en latín? ¿O en el bajo latín?

Comment: Ok, sólo agregar que no hay muchos casos en el CORDE de “bonito/a” antes del 1500, y siempre está la duda de su significado (“bonita moza”, en la _Celestina_, ¿es “buena moza” o “linda moza”?). Estoy casi seguro de que _bonitus_ no existe en latín (sí existe _bonitas_, bondad), pero les dejo a otros las respuestas a tus preguntas complementarias.